# Defining text size for Canvas.drawText() in res/values/dimens.xml

Tags: android, android-resources, text-size

In a Scrabble-like [word game app](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q5/TestScroll2) I am trying to draw black letters and values on yellow tiles.

While this works at Android emulators under Windows and Mac:

[image: Mac screenshot]

[image: Windows screenshot]

This doesn't work (the text size is too big) on real devices like Moto G, Nexus 1 and 4:

[image: Real devices]

I define the text sizes of **60sp** and **20sp** (I've tried [dp](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) too) in [res/values/dimens.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q5/TestScroll2/res/values/dimens.xml):

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="big_tile_letter">60sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="big_tile_value">20sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And then use them in my [BigTile.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q5/TestScroll2/src/de/afarber/testscroll2/BigTile.java) class:

```
    int letterSize = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.big_tile_letter);
    mLetterPaint = new Paint();
    mLetterPaint.setTextSize(letterSize);
    mLetterPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    Rect letterBounds = new Rect();  
    mLetterPaint.getTextBounds(letter, 0, letter.length(), letterBounds);
    mLetterX = 0.45f * (width - letterBounds.width());
    mLetterY = 0.45f * (height + letterBounds.height());

    canvas.drawText(letter, mLetterX, mLetterY, mLetterPaint);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the same dimension unit (`sp`, `dp`, whatever) for both the letters and the box where you're drawing it.

Comment: +1 but the problem is: the tiles are [png images](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q4/TestScroll2/res/drawable-mdpi/big_tile.png) and the letter and value are strings drawn with `canvas.drawText()` method.

Comment: Either scale the PNG to be proportional to your text size, or set your text size as a proportion of the PNG size.

Comment: Are you sure you have correct canvas scale when you draw the letters?

Answer (score 7):

If what you want to is to convert a value from the **R.dimen.something** into pixels so:

```
float textSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.something);
```

If what you want is to supply a manual value or something like that:

```
float maxTextSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, maxTextSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: But I am alreafy using `getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.something)` in my code (please see above). I don't understand how your answer helps

Comment: Are you sure that you've covered all the values for all the screen DPIs?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that comes to mind is that you are using `sp` values, which depend on the user setting in Settings / Display / Font Size. Can you check whether the setting is like `Large` or so - this would apply an additional scaling on your font size. Also, I believe for 2.x devices the default setting is different than for 4.x devices (not sure though).

You could try use `dp` values and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Sorry, just saw that you already tried that. Please ignore this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that setTextSize gets the size value in SP, not in pixels. In your case getDimensionPixelSize converts sp to pixels, and then setTextSize treats the pixels as sp, and scales up again.

> public void setTextSize(float size)
>
> Set the default text size to the given value, interpreted as "scaled
> pixel" units. This size is adjusted based on the current density and
> user font size preference.

To fix this, you can call

```
setTextSize (TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, letterSize)
```

Comment: But there is no `Paint.setTextSize()` taking 2 arguments?

Comment: The documentation you're quoting is for TextView, not Paint / TextPaint. Paint.setSize() uses pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dp` for the text sizes is definitely the way to go here, unless you wanted to manually compensate for the user's font size setting by scaling your images as well.

Your problem is that your `big_tile` image has inconsistent sizes in the mdpi (128x128) and xxhdpi (256x256) variants: xxhdpi should be 3 times the resolution of mdpi, but your image is only 2x the size, making it effectively ~85dp instead of 128dp.

I'm pretty sure I've seen Android Lint warn about this sort of stuff, try running it on your project.